# I'm trying to use the Intl package to format a date in Flutter. However, it's throwing me an error

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, datetime-format

Error Message:
The instance member 'today' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression

```
 DateTime today = DateTime.now();
  String date = new DateFormat.MMMd().format(today).toString();
```

Comment: Can you please provide more of the code where you use these expressions?
Maybe the complete Widget?

Answer (score 3):

Only `static` class members can be used in initializers.

You can either make the `today` variable `static`:

```
static DateTime today = DateTime.now();
String date = new DateFormat.MMMd().format(today).toString()
```

or move the initialization to a function (e.g., `initState`):

```
  DateTime today = DateTime.now();
  String date;
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    date = new DateFormat.MMMd().format(today).toString();
  }
```